# Stitched image not well aligned, hence leading to duplication

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

As shown in the image below, one image is not well aligned with another, which is causing duplication of vessels. How do I get rid of the duplication?

[image]

Th way I'm currently going about stitching is, I first find the keypoints using SIFT, I then use flannbasedmatcher to match the keypoints, find the homography, and then warp both; the stitched, and the to-bo-stitched image.

Comment: Either my eyes are terrible, or I can't see the duplication.  Please update your image to physically show us where the problem areas are.  Also, please show your code.  Simply telling us your steps is not productive in helping us solve your problem.

Comment: @rayryeng, Check the updated image. I'll edit the post with code once I refactor a few things, because it's too verbose otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

homography isnt perfect for non-planar scene or non-pure-rotation-camera, so there will always be errors SOMEWHERE in the aligned images.

Imho best to do (if you have to use homographies) is to distribute the errors over the whole image by making sure that the points used to compute the homography are distributed well over the whole image.

Or use a blending method that hides the duplicated parts in either of the images...

EDIT:

Here is a paper describing how to distribute the keypoints

http://www.lfb.rwth-aachen.de/bibtexupload/pdf/BEH10g.pdf

They claim to reduce the error.

EDIT 2:

another approach could be some kind of dense matching. Afaik there is a french team which try to registrate images by graph-based-matching, but I neither remember the name, nor whether this worked well. One idea coould be to coarse-align the image with your technique and afterwards start a dense matching by optical flow. If you are certain to know which pixel are correctly matched (and those pixel are not within a small part of the image), you can compute another homography with ALL the points (instead of using RANSAC).

Comment: How do I distribute the points computed by homography over the whole image?

Comment: Or put in a better way, how do I make sure that Homography computed is distributed over the whole image?

Comment: @syfy have a look at this paper from Behrens et al. http://www.lfb.rwth-aachen.de/bibtexupload/pdf/BEH10g.pdf

Comment: another approach could be some kind of dense matching. Afaik there is a french team which try to registrate images by graph-based-matching, but I neither remember the name, nor whether this worked well. One idea coould be to coarse-align the image with your technique and afterwards start a dense matching by optical flow. If you are certain to know which pixel are correctly matched (and those pixel are not within a small part of the image), you can compute another homography with ALL the points (instead of using RANSAC).

Comment: what blending method do you suggest to hide the duplication?

Comment: no concrete idea, would need more information about the images, the overlap-size and maybe some months of research... and information about what kind of blending you used so far.